# MS Outlook 2007 Strange UI - Navigation Pane / Sidebar

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-outlook-2007, user-interface

I apologize if this is not the appropriate place for this question.

Any idea what's causing my navigation pane in outlook to appear the way it is? I don't know of any changes to my system.

/resetnavpane did not work

[image]

Answer (score 0):

CCleaner was run on the machine recently. I restored the registry entries, scanned again, various .net framework v1.1 and 1.0 with "Missing Shared DLL". Looks to have fixed it, sorry for taking up space.